# Copodope Gopolopfop

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

#### The Language: Oppification

A funny language to speak is created by applying the following process to each word:

1. Place `op` after each consonant. So `Code` becomes `Copodope`.

Yes, that's it. For the purpose of this challenge, `y` is always a consonant.

#### The Challenge: De-oppification

Given an oppified word, return the original word. Input will only contain letters. The first letter may be capitalized. The original word will never be empty and will always contain a vowel.

#### Test Cases:

```
Oppified      ->         Original 
a                        a
I                        I
itop                     it
opop                     op
Opop                     Op
popopop                  pop
Copopop                  Cop
opopopop                 opop
Kopicopkop               Kick
Asopia                   Asia
soptopopop               stop
hopoopopsop              hoops
hopoopopedop             hooped
ooooohop                 oooooh
aaaopopaaa               aaaopaaa
Popopopsopicoplope       Popsicle
gopaloplopopopinopgop    galloping
aopopbopopopcopopop      aopbopcop
```

Comment: None of your test cases contain a vowel followed by `op`, so an answer along the lines of `replace(/(.)op/, '\1')` won't fail any of them. I suggest that you add a word like `hoop` or `looped` to the test cases.

Comment: @mbomb007 I added some more tricky test cases.

Comment: Does the answer only have to work for preoppified inputs or all inputs?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline "Given an oppified word"

Comment: Actually, all the people I know who speak this for fun agree that you add an "op" only right before a **vowel sound**. Code => Copode, Benji => Bopenjopi.

Comment: Can we add "mopmopmopbopopop" as a test case? :)

Comment: @Doorknob I think that approach also works correctly for those test cases, doesn't it?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe I'll run that by the person who told me.

Comment: WikiHow states "Some Oppish speakers insist on an “opp” after every single consonant, so the word, “flip” would be spelled, “f-opp l-opp i -p-opp.”"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>12</s>, 5 bytes

```
Í.“op
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLCoAwDET3OYx3EFfiQq8QP2hRTKDiLVx5Iz1YnbQKNjDzOul0D@E@susUDYGpJLeJkiikNlGJQ8Xr8gWVqOtEZ2DuwUzQ7V1OUAP/46G3uh0kxMwWwqhJJZ8@XPCSRmyWyDZuFR2tY5c2ZV2yBw)

```
00000000: cd2e 936f 70                             ...op
```

Saved 7 bytes thanks to [@Xnor's realization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124770/31716) that since the input must always be opped, we don't have to check for vowels.

Comment: Hmm, this seems so hard to beat...

Comment: The hex dump: `...op`  Is making me laugh way harder than it should

Answer (score 12):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 9 bytes

```
(?!\G)op
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCoQwDETv@QsPC/oVsngQ8bD7AR7MqmhRTLD9/@7EKtjAzOuk02MKbuf4yus@5mXW1YUoxcjUkAtAUcjHROUcqi6XO2hF3SC6At8ezAQN13KBGvgHT6PV7SAhZrYQRt9U8unDDS9pxmY72cbtorN17PJL2ZDsDw)

Instead of checking that the preceding character is a consonant, we just make sure that the current `op` is not adjacent to either the beginning of the string or the previous match. The only case where we could match an incorrect `op` is if the original string contained an `op` (resulting in `opop`). But in that case we'll just remove the first `op` instead of the second and the result will be the same.

Comment: Wouldn't this give an incorrect answer for an input like `loop`?

Comment: @Leo `loop` is not a valid input because you can't obtain it from oppifying another word.

Comment: @MartinEnder But `lopoop` (the oppified version of `loop`) is valid, and doesn't get de-oppified to `loop`.

Comment: @Imus no, the oppified version of `loop` is `lopoopop`.

Comment: realised my mistake as well shortly after posting it :) was too slow in deleting. Good point.

Comment: @MartinEnder you're right. Sadly, it looks like simply replacing `.op` with the first character, as some answers in other languages do, [is shorter](https://tio.run/##TUxBCoNADLznHRX0UvAJ4qGIB32CcSt2qZjQ3f@vE9eCCcxMJpn8luh3TkX5mlL5rETpUafE1JGPGEQBg4HK2dReLH@jF/VO9AvZBGgmYLyWH6CJcNPL2@JWcIiZzQTRmEMhP9xwSSs226mt/S66WsaGOXsu0wE) (but less interesting, in my opinion)

Comment: @Leo Yes, I noticed in the meantime, but I'll leave that to either NoOneIsHere or Doorknob.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub('(.)op',r'\1',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHBbsMgDIbP5SlYLkmkqNJ2rNTD1F2qHtoHqDSRlCRWKbaAHfb0mSG0yUCK8effP1ag3zCi/Zj6/XUy6tHelPQ7p7f@p63KalsjlY0rr@9l42sBD0IXpNNT0D74fVEUSi5LieMqOwoISwYBSSAtAInBeQXOEdBKQpi2OKzYITNcCfEpPEF3f8ITEnRId8afHl5TfnrmSviwtDMJ2WBEJJ/xyCRCn7m@/ef6FseIa8xjpDNDpRQSf9IvieeUiQt7QWd0xJf5Qj8PadhNDMpwBDtweeAOk3jcYJGG6IvUInVp8uTazvVuDvwYQvTopAGrJViZ3mjryUCoyqst653YGN2HRjoYxiD3SZkFtZAbp7vvKOBKXyVNpNDLV@GNeziy0YYc2DA7NTLbZpmYa8UXWl1Mfw)

If I'm not mistaken, you can just substitute all `?op` with `?` without caring about vowels. If the original string contains `op`, then it's oppified to `opop`, and the replacement returns it to `op` and no further. This is because the pattern matches for `?op` cannot overlap, so only one `op` is removed.

A non-regex solution is 5 bytes longer.

**[Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[0]+f(s[1+2*(s[1:3]=='op'):])
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dZJNb8IwDIbP@FdkvQADTRvckHpA2wVxYHeGptCmrUWWWHUu@/WdkyKEWJtIsfQ@r50v029ovFt1XZVb/XMuteINK@1KxcfX06Ka8fFtsXqOYbM@5fnU03S@Oc27YDhwnmWZViNDw24M7QCDp0GEATyNME9wGGMHAvI0nCoivI9BAeDHUqMIe09YeLr843ssLrBlwUOPsGXUIDAM1maRoREQGT/iRmS@YVM@8IhNCT6OZujYCYDWOqZLePyaCGSBz/5s3N/QStWrQwBjYQ3UYrQJxYnOU91vWGtro1BD2uTcG4r7y@okiyRtAlD5Vll0RqFTqXtemCyG2fTLSUvBpMW6CUtlTRVUnpxXwxzUpDXF95VUs@SMKlbqBp7ylCqFJtSiC@qu3vJmg55lH96ZrPsD)

Comment: You can import `re` *after* you reference it‽

Comment: @Adám Python doesn't evaluate it when the function is defined, only when it's called.

Comment: Wow, it's been a while since I've seen anyone use an interrobang. I guess that's a way to golf your comment a little.

Comment: @Baldrickk But in *bytes*, the interrobang has >= bytes than just the string "?!"

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>15</s> 8 bytes

```
(.)op
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ08zv4BLxfD/fwA)

*-7 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by replacing `[^aeiou]` with `.`. See [_@xnor_'s explanation in his Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124762/copodope-gopolopfop/124770#124770).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 10 + 1 = 11 bytes

```perl
s/.\Kop//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXy/GO79AXz/9//@M/IJ8ICoozi/4l19QkpmfV/xft8DXVM/A0AAA)

Run with `-p` (1 byte penalty); golfing languages might do implicit I/O automatically, but Perl needs an option for it.

When I saw [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124770/62131), I realised it could be improved using a Perl-specific regex feature; `s/a\Kb/c/g` is equivalent to `s/ab/ac/g` (in other words, the `s///` only replaces the things after the first `\K`). So here's how it looks in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>103</s> 92 bytes

Must... compile... Go built-in functions have weird names. :P

```
import."regexp"
func f(s string)string{return MustCompile("(.)op").ReplaceAllString(s,"$1")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7BagQhDL3PVwTpQWER9rrQw9BTKYWlPZZSZFArqyaoA4Vlvj11nNIEkpf3XkI8MpnlZryFZEKeppAISwPhUhP/A1bBB9aiWG9/SExuzQs4WaG2ErJXR7sX29aS4XWt7QkThWilkFohCaXfLEWz2DnG92GW9SQezkJtPI7tD0h1n6CHwwJfJwhweYRicn8Pq56Lrx/nyyccnuFLTV/7rRazdDIoNZRt2pgNP3NoSEw4kl@QwoJ063CuHRvutf2J373uoFOMe3SCr4dYj8WIZNkjmTjwniEjdeYX)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 36 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("#.\Kop#","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6sUkF8AgsX5BZnJ@QU5@QWpStZc9nZARbYFRanp8UWpBTmJyakaSsp6Md75BcpKOkpKOmC9mtb//wMA)

Comment: How is this supposed to be run?

Comment: It fails for the first two test cases. Use `preg_replace` to fix.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by renaming the variable to any single character, $a for instance

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie `$argn` is a reserved variable which is availbale when PHP is run with the `-R`Option from the command line

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know that. The online tester doesn't account for it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell (<del>93</del> <del>62</del> 61 Bytes)

```
a(x:'o':'p':r)|notElem x"aeiouAEIOU"=x:a r
a(x:r)=x:a r
a x=x
```

thanks to @nimi suggestions in comments!

Comment: Some tips: as you are using `v` and `o` only once, you can inline it. `notElem` is shorter than `not(...elem...)`. You can replace the `&&` in a guard with a `,`. The last case for `a` can be written as `a x=x`. No need for `()` in `x:(a r)`.

Comment: ... oh, and the test for `=="op"` can be replaced with a literal pattern match: `a(x:'o':'p':r)|notElem x"aeiouAEIOU"=x:a r`

Comment: Updated. thanks @nimi

Comment: One more byte to save: you can omit the space between `x` and `"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
r"%Vop"_g
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ciIlVm9wIl9n&input=InBvcG9wb3Ai)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

Add `f=` at beginning and invoke like `f(arg)`.

```
s=>s.replace(/([^aeiou])op/gi,"$1")
```

I am surprised no one posted a JavaScript solution yet....

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
s=>s.replace(/([^aeiou])op/gi,"$1")

console.log("a" + " -> " + f("a"));
console.log("I" + " -> " + f("I"));
console.log("itop" + " -> " + f("itop"));
console.log("opop" + " -> " + f("opop"));
console.log("Opop" + " -> " + f("Opop"));
console.log("popopop" + " -> " + f("popopop"));
console.log("Copopop" + " -> " + f("Copopop"));
console.log("opopopop" + " -> " + f("opopopop"));
console.log("Kopicopkop" + " -> " + f("Kopicopkop"));
console.log("Asopia" + " -> " + f("Asopia"));
console.log("soptopopop" + " -> " + f("soptopopop"));
console.log("hopoopopsop" + " -> " + f("hopoopopsop"));
console.log("hopoopopedop" + " -> " + f("hopoopopedop"));
console.log("ooooohop" + " -> " + f("ooooohop"));
console.log("aaaopopaaa" + " -> " + f("aaaopopaaa"));
console.log("Popopopsopicoplope" + " -> " + f("Popopopsopicoplope"));
console.log("gopaloplopopopinopgop" + " -> " + f("gopaloplopopopinopgop"));
console.log("aopopbopopopcopopop" + " -> " + f("aopopbopopopcopopop"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 83 bytes

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{for(;*v[1];strchr("aAeEiIoOuU",putchar(*v[1]++))?:printf("op"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@bmJmnkaxTppmckVikpVVmXZ2WX6RhrVUWbRhrXVxSlJxRpKGU6JjqmumZ718aqqRTUFoCUqoBVqGtralpb1VQlJlXkqahlF@gpKlpXfv////E/IKk/ILk/IKvefm6yYnJGakA)

Answer (score 0):

## Crystal, 39 Bytes

```
def o(s)s.gsub(/([^aeiou])op/,"\\1")end
```

### How it works

It simply searches for each consonant, followed by the sequence `op`. If so, replace that sequence only with the consonant found before: `([^aeiou])`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZU69DsIgEN59CsMEibHxEYyTcdDdakIptsSmd/HawafHow1ClRv4/u7HvN406M772j7WIEnRtqGxkoW83rV1MN4UYLERZbkTyva1R04JLdRqAscI3AAYMWDC5wwjYG4dlhR@7BOgM4DPpOyJpe9qJsOyo2USOP1Lts4WhdcmrrUOEf6icpnn0nxBx@3RaTjXTVIo1wM22aCgVbNl4mn@Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34</s> <s>27</s> 22 + 1 = 23 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to RJHunter.*

+1 byte for the `-p` flag.

```ruby
$_.gsub!(/(.)op/,'\1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU1BCsJADLznF4LQFrTFJ4gn8aAPECRbZV0sTWjag583Jt0KbmBmdpJJhim8Vde3OsoUVmVT1hVxsymuu6JSRThCGomB2ODswDQXHBamn3EiTi3xy@ReTCMYjkvzaehC/vTj7nF/5gAiumkElxySvLCzSYjW6WbtlXri6Bn/hOy1mT52M1EvuuUv)

Comment: Using Ruby's `-p` option will cost a byte but allow your script to start directly with `gsub`.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 18 bytes

```
/op/.//../o\p//.//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz@/QF9PX19PTz8/pkAfxPwfkF8AgsX5BZnJ@QU5@QWp/wE)

Note that this snippet wants to replace `op` with a `.`, but later on there is a replacement defined where `op` is being put back into the string. That second instruction would have the `op` replaced by a `.` (and thus insert a `.` into the end result), so I've used a `\` between the `o` and `p` to break the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
'(.)op'⎕R'\1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PyU1v@BR2wR1DT3N/AL1R31Tg9RjDNUh4odWqCeqKyioe4KIzBKgPJDOL4DQ/lC6IL8AJuSMYOYjCXvnF2Qm5xdkQ3iOxUAu2FggowShKgPIALGLUbmpKVADQSADwk5MTARJASkQLwBiRjHElhygFpBoOlA@B8wFwcy8/IJ0qGYQPwkinAyzHgA)

Simply PCRE **R**eplace any character followed by "op" with the character itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>36</s> 26 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(.)op","$1")
```

-10 bytes by replacing `[^aeiou]` with `.`, thanks to [*@xnor*'s explanation in his Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124770/52210).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZA9a8MwEIZ3/4pDZLCgMXQOLYROoTQpdCwdLrLqKFGkw1ICpfi3u6fYS4ciVQJ9Pu97H0e84tKTdsf2NCqLIcALGvddARgXdf@JSsM2XQHeYm9cB6qeD0Gu@H2oeAkRo1GwBQcPMIblY2h6TZbFa2trUTfSk7gTi3shx1US0GVvWTDrrt60cOa4s/X7B6Ccg36FqM@Nv8SG@CtaV7tG1QKFvIX/m9hkCRM5qxzkqQDalUDkqcjsqZDzpYbPnozydCpA14HZfG@ZioXBD0wlMPyD1W1J@WkcCkBETKa8ZdHXqagwNcxyJllJx872xqZpnKeuJKcE7yeN@tXJoRrGHw)

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 22 bytes

```
sed -E 's/(.)op/\1/g'
```

Reads from STDIN until EOF and outputs de-oppified string
Uses same length reduction technique from [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124770/14280)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
gsub("(.)op","\\1",scan(,''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUzNCsIwDL7vMXJZC0XwEYYn8aAPsEtWxyyOJZj5/DVpR8GG8uX7yffJeZHv5MCdPDEEGMczBIm4udD33mdA6OCqP@3qd0Bc4F5hEOJkCSY@nEvbyN6rXR3qTS8i8bsQRDRZQYl27S2md2Sr/LH5WeijxqRWrapbl0lTdWLrWbR9LRmbtBGrAvkH)

Much like most other solutions here, captures character followed by op, replaces it with character itself.